# Playframework controller receiving deep JSON object

Tags: ajax, json, playframework

I'm using JQuery to post a JSON Object (3 levels deep) to Play!

```
$.post("saveIt", {id1: {key1: {val1: ...}...}...}, function ...
```

how do I access this structure from within Play! / Java?

Answer (score 0):

Use gson in your controller method to deserialize it into a java object

```
MyObject myObject = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(params.get("saveIt"), MyObject.class);
```